# How do I prevent my functional test cases from creating ActiveResource calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activeresource

I've got a controller that fires off an ActiveResource request during its execution. Included in that request is an id that is generated as a part of my controller execution (so, **/a/b/{my_id}/c.xml**, where **my_id** is a value that is generated by the controller).

I don't want my test cases to trigger actual live requests, but I also don't want the calls to fail (I need a 200 response).

I've looked at HttpMock, which seems like a good solution, but it does not appear to allow for wild cards or regular expressions within the respond_to block (e.g.) which are necessary because the generated id is a part of the request.

Is there a way to do this? I've been looking but I haven't seen anything yet, and the HttpMock documentation doesn't mention it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend either mocking out the web service calls with FakeWeb or using traditional mocking on the ActiveResource layer itself.

```
  require 'fakeweb'

  FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, "http://example.com/test1", :body => "Hello World!")

  Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://example.com/test1"))
  => "Hello World!"
```

...or mocking with Mocha:

```
  MyActiveResource.stubs(:create => true)
```